# Выбрать последнюю запись по одному полю MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `visit` (
  `id` BIGINT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `siteId` BIGINT(6) NOT NULL,
  `clientId` BIGINT(6) NULL,
  `guest` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `ip` LONGTEXT  NULL,
  `os` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `screen` LONGTEXT  NULL,
  `page` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `referer` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `device` LONGTEXT  NULL,
  `location` LONGTEXT  NULL,
  `created` TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `siteId`),
  INDEX `fk_visit_site1_idx` (`siteId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_visit_site1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`siteId`)
    REFERENCES `site` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

в неё докидываются записи но эти записи могут иметь одинаковые поля `siteId` и `clientId`.

Мне нужно выбрать самые последние записи по каждому `clientId`. `siteId` мы задаём сами.

Я сделал такое:

```
SELECT v.id AS id, v.siteId, v.clientId, v.guest, MAX(v.ip) AS ip, MAX(v.os) AS os, MAX(v.screen) AS screen, MAX(v.device) AS device, MAX(v.location) AS location, MAX(v.date) AS date, MAX(v.time) AS time, MAX(v.created) AS created FROM visit AS v WHERE siteId = ? GROUP BY v.id, v.siteId, v.clientId ORDER BY MAX(v.created) DESC;
```

Но происходят дублирования, да и MAX функция как-то не так выбирает.

Подскажите пожалуйста поправленный SQL запрос.

P.S может есть резон вообще сделать две таблицы?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `visit` (
  `id` BIGINT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `siteId` BIGINT(6) NOT NULL,
  `clientId` BIGINT(6) NULL,
  `guest` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `created` TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `siteId`),
  INDEX `fk_visit_site1_idx` (`siteId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_visit_site1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`siteId`)
    REFERENCES `site` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `visitinfo` (
  `id` BIGINT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `visitId` BIGINT(6) NOT NULL,
  `ip` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `os` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `screen` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `page` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `referer` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `device` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `created` TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `visitId`),
  INDEX `fk_visitinfo_visit2_idx` (`visitId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_visitinfo_visit2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`visitId`)
    REFERENCES `visit` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Получите в подзапросе максимальное `created` для каждого `clientId`. Используйте полученное в качестве критерия отбора. Если при этом остаются дубликаты - формулируйте дополнительные критерии отбора. **PS.** *я не прошу сделать за меня, а поправить то что есть* От того, что Вы напишете слово SELECT, "сделай за меня" не превращается в "помоги мне".

Comment: Хорошо. Вот я получил все последние `id` записей: `SELECT MAX(vc.id) FROM visit AS vc WHERE vc.siteId = 2 GROUP BY vc.clientId ORDER BY MAX(vc.created) DESC`. Как его соединить с выбором полей уже по конкретной записи? подскажете?

Comment: Для отбора нужна пара (MAX(created), clientId). По ней связываешь подзапрос со второй копией исходной таблицы. И эта... сортировка в подзапросе бессмысленна.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  visit
WHERE
  ......
GROUP BY
  clientId, siteId
HAVING
  created = MAX(created);
```

Это если интересует выборка по всем группам. Если же нужна выборка последней записи в конкретной группе, то так

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  visit
WHERE
  clientId = ? AND
  siteId = ?
ORDER BY
  created DESC
LIMIT 1
```

И не плохо было бы добавить индекс по полю `created`

Comment: Теоретически, поле `created` неуникально, лучше, наверное, ориентироваться на `id`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `visit` (
>   `id` BIGINT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `siteId` BIGINT(6) NOT NULL,
>   `clientId` BIGINT(6) NULL,
>   `guest` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 1,
>   `ip` LONGTEXT  NULL,
>   `os` LONGTEXT NULL,
>   `screen` LONGTEXT  NULL,
>   `page` LONGTEXT NULL,
>   `referer` LONGTEXT NULL,
>   `device` LONGTEXT  NULL,
>   `location` LONGTEXT  NULL,
>   `created` TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `siteId`));
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `visit` (`siteId`, `clientId`) VALUES (1, 1);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `visit` (`siteId`, `clientId`) VALUES (1, 2);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `visit` (`siteId`, `clientId`) VALUES (1, 1);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `visit` (`siteId`, `clientId`) VALUES (1, 2);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `visit` (`siteId`, `clientId`) VALUES (3, 1);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `visit` (`siteId`, `clientId`) VALUES (3, 1);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `visit` (`siteId`, `clientId`) VALUES (3, 2);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `visit` (`siteId`, `clientId`) VALUES (3, 2);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   `id`,
>   `siteId`,
>   `clientId`,
>   `guest`,
>   `created`
> FROM `visit`
> ```
>
> ```
> id | siteId | clientId | guest | created                   
> -: | -----: | -------: | ----: | :-------------------------
>  1 |      1 |        1 |     1 | 2018-07-06 20:08:46.040493
>  2 |      1 |        2 |     1 | 2018-07-06 20:08:46.088735
>  3 |      1 |        1 |     1 | 2018-07-06 20:08:46.117578
>  4 |      1 |        2 |     1 | 2018-07-06 20:08:46.136165
>  5 |      3 |        1 |     1 | 2018-07-06 20:08:46.149508
>  6 |      3 |        1 |     1 | 2018-07-06 20:08:46.168141
>  7 |      3 |        2 |     1 | 2018-07-06 20:08:46.219538
>  8 |      3 |        2 |     1 | 2018-07-06 20:08:46.235341
> ```

---

Для всех siteId

> ```
> SELECT 
>   V.`id`,
>   V.`siteId`,
>   V.`clientId`,   
>   V.`created`
> FROM `visit` AS V
>   JOIN 
>   (
>   SELECT 
>     `siteId`,
>     `clientId`,    
>     MAX(`created`) AS `created`
>   FROM `visit`
>   GROUP BY
>     `siteId`,
>     `clientId`    
>   ) AS VMAX 
>   ON 
>     V.`siteId` = VMAX.`siteId` AND 
>     V.`clientId` = VMAX.`clientId` AND 
>     V.`created` = VMAX.`created`
> ```
>
> ```
> id | siteId | clientId | created                   
> -: | -----: | -------: | :-------------------------
>  3 |      1 |        1 | 2018-07-06 20:08:46.117578
>  4 |      1 |        2 | 2018-07-06 20:08:46.136165
>  6 |      3 |        1 | 2018-07-06 20:08:46.168141
>  8 |      3 |        2 | 2018-07-06 20:08:46.235341
> ```

---

Для siteId = 1

> ```
> SELECT 
>   V.`id`,
>   V.`clientId`,   
>   V.`created`
> FROM `visit` AS V
>   JOIN 
>   (
>   SELECT 
>     `clientId`,
>     MAX(`created`) AS `created`
>   FROM `visit`
>   WHERE
>     `siteId` = 1   -- ВЫБОР siteId
>   GROUP BY
>     `clientId`
>   ) AS VMAX 
>   ON 
>     V.`clientId` = VMAX.`clientId` AND 
>     V.`created` = VMAX.`created`
> ```
>
> ```
> id | clientId | created                   
> -: | -------: | :-------------------------
>  3 |        1 | 2018-07-06 20:08:46.117578
>  4 |        2 | 2018-07-06 20:08:46.136165
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3455043eb8a0af3b34bc2fe6307103e)*